# Listing sorted text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make ordered list in my little script, but I have no idea how to start it. Can you give me some advice? I think it would be more usefull than just code. The question is: how to display it on website as ordered list?
Here is my javascript and HTML:

```js
var numnames = 0;
var names    = new Array();

function SortNames() {
    thename         = document.theform.newname.value;
    names[numnames] = thename;
    names[numnames] = thename.toUpperCase();
    numnames++;
    names.sort();
    document.theform.sorted.value=names.join("\n");
}
```

```html
<h1>Sorting list</h1>
    <p>Instert text</p>
<form name="theform">
    <p>Text:</p>
    <input type="text" name="newname" size="20">
    <input type="button" name="addname" value="add" onclick="SortNames();">
    <h2>Sorted txt</h2>
    <textarea cols="80" rows="20" name="sorted">
        text
   </textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. The text you input seems to get sorted.

Comment: Your script already orders the results when displaying them. What is your question??

Comment: The question is: how to display it on website as ordered list

Comment: You already did that (This is a website, your text is ordered). So, what's the question?

Comment: When you say "ordered list", do you mean `<ol>`?

Comment: I want to display:
1.
2.
3. etc

Comment: `names[numnames] = thename;
    names[numnames] = thename.toUpperCase();` makes no sense, remove the first one.

Comment: @vlaz exactly I mean <ol> :)

Comment: So loop over your array and build a list.

Comment: @epascarello thank you for advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like this?

```js
var numnames = 0;
var names    = new Array();

function SortNames() {
    thename         = document.theform.newname.value;
    names[numnames] = thename;
    names[numnames] = thename.toUpperCase();
    numnames++;
    names.sort();

    var ol = document.getElementById('out');
    ol.innerHTML = '';
    names.forEach(function(name) {
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = name;
      ol.appendChild(li);
    });
}
```

```html
<h1>Sorting list</h1>
    <p>Instert text</p>
<form name="theform">
    <p>Text:</p>
    <input type="text" name="newname" size="20">
    <input type="button" name="addname" value="dodaj" onclick="SortNames();">
    <h2>Sorted txt</h2>
    <ol id='out'></ol>
</form>
```

Comment: @Olchus feel free to mark it as correct answer if it solved ur problem

Comment: I would suggest appending new `li` and then sorting, instead of `.innerHTML = ''`. This will make sure elements are not rendered again and any attached events are not removed

Comment: @YannickHuber thank you for advice. I still feel like newbee on stackoverflow

Comment: @Rajesh I inserted a native element right into the list as you can see in my response. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41767020

Answer (score 1):

You can do very similar to what you've already done, but rather than write the element to a `textarea` write them to an `ol` element.

```js
var numnames = 0;
var names    = new Array();

function SortNames() {
    thename         = document.theform.newname.value;
    names[numnames] = thename; // NOTE: this line is obsolete
    names[numnames] = thename.toUpperCase();
    numnames++;
    names.sort();
    var ol = document.getElementById("list");
    ol.innerHTML = names.map(function(n){ 
      return "<li>" + n + "</li>"
    }).join("") ;
}
```

```html
<h1>Sorting list</h1>
    <p>Instert text</p>
<form name="theform">
    <p>Text:</p>
    <input type="text" name="newname" size="20">
    <input type="button" name="addname" value="dodaj" onclick="SortNames();">
    <h2>Sorted txt</h2>
    <ol id="list"></ol>
</form>
```

If you *wanted* to keep this in a textarea just manually create the numbers

```js
var numnames = 0;
var names    = new Array();

function SortNames() {
    thename         = document.theform.newname.value;
    names[numnames] = thename;
    names[numnames] = thename.toUpperCase();
    numnames++;
    names.sort();
    document.theform.sorted.value=names.map(function(n,i){
        return (i + 1) + '. ' + n;
    }).join('\n')
}
```

```html
<h1>Sorting list</h1>
    <p>Instert text</p>
<form name="theform">
    <p>Text:</p>
    <input type="text" name="newname" size="20">
    <input type="button" name="addname" value="add" onclick="SortNames();">
    <h2>Sorted txt</h2>
    <textarea cols="80" rows="20" name="sorted">
        text
   </textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Your map needs a join

Comment: @jamiec do you think I could do this in textarea? :> I'm curious

Comment: @Olchus of course you can, you just need to manually create the numbers

Comment: Oo ... using `.map()`. I like it. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this (I also simplified your code):

```js
var names = new Array(); // you should use var names = [];

function SortNames() {
    names.push(document.theform.newname.value);
    names.sort();
    var list = document.getElementById('list');
    list.innerHTML = '<li>' + names.join('</li><li>') + '</li>';
}
```

```html
<h1>Sorting list</h1>
    <p>Instert text</p>
<form name="theform">
    <p>Text:</p>
    <input type="text" name="newname" size="20">
    <input type="button" name="addname" value="dodaj" onclick="SortNames();">
    <h2>Sorted txt</h2>
    <ol id="list"></ol>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp) it about how to build list by html

Another one thing you should check is how to work with DOM elements, simply like

```
document.getElementById("main").innerHtml = "<ol><li></li></ol>"
```

check this out [js DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)

Comment: `innerHTML` and at least make it an `ol` as the only clue the OP has given us is "ordered list"#

Answer (score 0):

```js
var names    = new Array();
var ol = document.getElementById("sorted");
function SortNames() {
    var input = document.theform.newname; // get the input
    thename = input.value; // store its value
    input.value = ""; // clear it's value
    
    names.push(thename.toUpperCase()); // push it into the array in uppercase
    
    names.sort(); // sort the array
    
    ol.innerHTML = "";
    names.forEach(function(name){
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.textContent = name;
        ol.appendChild(li);
    });
}
```

```html
<h1>Sorting list</h1>
<p>Instert text</p>
<form name="theform">
  <p>Text:</p>
  <input type="text" name="newname" size="20">
  <input type="button" name="addname" value="dodaj" onclick="SortNames();">
  <h2>Sorted txt</h2>
  <ol id="sorted"></ol>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of recreating the HTML list each time, just insert the element right into the list.

```js
var form = document.forms['theform'];
var list = document.getElementById('name-list');
var names = new Array();

function sortNames(button) {
  var name = form['newname'].value.toUpperCase();
  if (names.indexOf(name) > -1) {
    alert('Name already present!');
    return;
  }

  // Add the new name and sort the list.
  names.push(name);
  names.sort();

  // Create new list item.
  var listItem = document.createElement('LI');
  listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));

  // Insert the new list item into the list.
  var newIndex = names.indexOf(name);
  list.insertBefore(listItem, list.childNodes[newIndex]);
}
```

```html
<h1>Sorting list</h1>
<p>Instert text with auto-sorting.</p>
<form name="theform">
  <p>
    Text:
    <input type="text" name="newname" size="20">
    <input type="button" name="addname" value="Add" onclick="sortNames(this)">
  </p>
  <h2>Sorted txt</h2>
  <ol id="name-list"></ol>
</form>
```